# Determine recently queued/number of queues for titles, recently watched, etc via Netflix API

Tags: api, queue, watch, netflix, instant

I've seen other websites (InstantWatcher & Instant Watch DB) doing this, but how? I don't see anything in the API that exposes this kind of data? This is driving me batty! How are they doing it?! Am I missing something in the API??

And there is nothing in Google-land regarding this. I've looked...

Comment: Okay, so I've now found the Netflix RSS feeds which was promising when I heard about it, but after looking it still doesn't give me the information I was looking for...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to start tracking this data on your own. You can put a JavaScript hook on the "play" or "queue" buttons/links that pings you server and increments the queue/play count for the title in your datastore.

If you look at the add queue button on instantwatchdb.com, you'll see this kind of hook:

```
<a href="#" class="modal" 
onclick="javascript:nflx.addToQueue(
'http://api.netflix.com/catalog/titles/movies/60024224', 
-230, -15, '8zgw3pprk2n5byjfuv3f52y4', 'instant', 'title_links'); 
logQueue('166252'); return false; return false;">Add to Instant Queue</a>
```

The `logQueue` call is to an custom JavaScript that increments the local queue count.

```
function logQueue(movieId)
{
  new Ajax.Request('/ajax/activity/queue', {
    method: 'post',
    parameters: {
      movie: movieId
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: I was hoping this wasn't going to be the answer because to render good data you'll need a decent amount of traffic to queue and play movies. Certainly possible, just not ideal. Thanks!